Horror anthology help
Please I need help.. Looking for a horror movie that has a few short stories. I only remember 1 story & some of the main action between stories. The main action was an unseen narrator hiding in a house with newspaper covering the windows, he was videotaping the cops across the street. There was a child stuck in the house with him that he told these cautionary tales to.
The short I remember was about a woman going on a blind date it turned into a one night stand but then quickly became a 3 some. You think the 2 men are going to kill her but it turns out she's really the killer.
I think this movie is from late 80's or early 90's

Sounds like you're thinking of Canadian TV movie - Twists of Terror aka Primal Scream
Here's the linkage -
Twist Of Terror - Wiki
In particular, the 3rd story matches your description pretty accurately:

"Stolen Moments" shows a shy and pretty Cindy Craig who has trouble
  meeting men, living her life in an apartment with a plethora of pets.
  One evening she goes to a bar and is picked up by two men, they go
  back to an abandoned house and have sex, but then she murders them and
  resumes her life as the 'quiet' woman she is.


Welcome! Thanks for helping out!  In general, Link-only answers are discouraged due to potential link death.  Now, i know that's unlikely with Wikipedia but, in the off chance that it happens, could you please flesh out your answer by including the basic info from the page, particularly anything from the plot section that is identical to the points the OP has mentioned.

Thank you Jarowdowsky... I do believe that is the one. I am a horror fanatic but have been having trouble lately remember movie trivia. I appreciate your help
